# problem in insert OLE object to MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am using MS-Access 2007 forms to insert a pdf file to my database. unfortunatly when I try to insert my object to database(right click on attachment textbox in my form & click on insert object) I receive below error:

> "The OLE object you tried to create or edit is too large to save"

would you help me how I can solve this error?

I check my disk space. I have enough space and my pdf is just 274KB.
is there any limitation for access to upload a file? if yes how I can customize it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I never used OLE objects in access, I always preferred to put all documents in a subfolder of the database folder and store just a relative path to file inside the database. Maybe this is an alternative to your approach.

Edit: How big is your file? I once read access has limit for the maximum file size.

Comment: I agree. I fyou are saving .pdf files, why clog up your database with such large objects?just create a feild to store a path as Pedro suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I am running into a similar situation. When you insert an OLE object into an Access database, Access stores both the object itself (in this case the PDF file) plus some OLE overhead. Both the object and OLE overhead are stored together as a single blob in the field. For Word documents and Excel files the OLE overhead is relatively small. But for PDF files the overhead is > 5MB! I have no idea why or if there is a way to reduce it. It has prevented me from storing PDF files in the database.